# Equal elements in list of lists. Delete one

Tags: python

I have a list of lists

```
list = [[-2.0, 5.0], [-1.0, -3.0], [1.0, 3.0], [2.0, -5.0]]
```

What I want to do is delete one the elements of same value should I divide first element with second. For example `[-2.0, 5.0] = -2/5` and `[2.0, -5.0] = -2/5`. I want to delete either `[-2.0, 5.0]` or `[2.0, -5.0]` since they produce the same value.

Any ideas?

Comment: Why are these all `float` values if they're all rounded to the nearest integer?

Comment: `list` is a keyword. use something else.

Answer (score 1):

Can i try like this:

Tuple could be a dictionary key, so I converted the list into tuple after changing to abs 
   value of the list element and keeping the original list as the values.

```
>>> lis
[[-2.0, 5.0], [-1.0, -3.0], [1.0, 3.0], [2.0, -5.0]]
>>> dict([(tuple([abs(x[0]), abs(x[1])]), x) for x in lis]).values()
[[2.0, -5.0], [1.0, 3.0]]
>>>
```

Comment: I like this better than my solution! +1

Answer (score 0):

Assuming all your values are all floats (so you can always use float division) you can do the following:

```
my_list = [[-2.0, 5.0], [-1.0, -3.0], [1.0, 3.0], [2.0, -5.0]]
values_seen = []
new_list = []

for x,y in my_list:
    if x/y in values_seen:
        continue
    else:
        values_seen.append(x/y)
        new_list.append([x,y])
```

Now the list you want will be stored as `new_list`. Note that you should avoid writing a value to the keyword `list` as you have above.

*Clarification, I am assuming that if you have any more than 2 values that return the same ratio (for example `[[1,3],[2,6],[3,9]]`) you will want to keep only one of these.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to eliminate all equivalent fractions (meaning [-2.0, 5.0] and [4.0, -10.0] are considered equivalent), then the following code would work.

```
seen = set()
for numerator, denominator in lst:
    quotient = numerator / denominator
    if quotient not in seen:
        seen.add(quotient)
        yield numerator, denominator
```

Otherwise, if you want the final list to contain both [-2.0, 5.0] and [4.0, -10.0]:

```
seen = set()
for numerator, denominator in lst:
    value = (abs(numerator), abs(denominator), sign(numerator)*sign(denominator))
    if value not in seen:
        seen.add(value)
        yield numerator, denominator
```

If you're writing this in Python, a language that lacks a `sign` function, you'll either need to use [math.copysign](https://docs.python.org/2/library/math.html#math.copysign) or `(numerator > 0) ^ (denominator > 0)` where `^` is the xor operator.

This code assumes both numerator and denominator are nonzero.

If you really are keeping a list of numerator-denominator number pairs, consider storing the pairs as immutable tuples or better yet, as [Python fractions](https://docs.python.org/2/library/fractions.html).

Answer (score 0):

Quick and dirty way, since keys in a dictionary are unique.

```
{num/denom : [num, denom] for (num, denom) in lst}.values()
```

In general, comparing floats using == is unreliable, it's normally better to check if they're within a tolerance. e.g.

```
abs(x-y) < tolerance
```

a more robust way would might look like the following. An else attached to a for loop just means do this unless you exited the loop early. It's quite handy. This version, however, is quadratic rather than linear time.

```
div = lambda x,y : x/y

unique = []
for j in range(len(lst)):
    for i in range(j):
        if abs( div(*lst[i])-div(*lst[j]) ) < tolerance:
            break
    else
        unique.append(lst[j])

unique
```

Comment: `__hash__` and `__eq__` both have problems with precision on floats, so using a hash table wouldn't help solve the problem. For example, if hash(-1/3.0) != hash(1/-3.0), you would have two entries in your hash table.

Comment: Thanks, my answer wasn't clear at all. I didn't mean to claim that the dictionary version will solve the tolerance problem, I meant that it's simple and quick and will remove duplicates. For the builtin types that are hashable at least, if two things compare equal then `__hash__` will return the same value for both.

Comment: Might be worth re-ordering your solution as "quick and dirty dict" then "considering tolerance". All the necessary content is there, just confusing at first glance.

Answer (score 0):

I would first get a unique set of ratios using `set`:

```
In [1]: lst = [[-2.0, 5.0], [-1.0, -3.0], [1.0, 3.0], [2.0, -5.0]]

In [2]: rs = list(set([ l[0]/l[1]  for l in lst]))
```

And then just filter out the first occurance of the ratios:

```
In [3]: [ filter(lambda m: m[0]/m[1] == r  , lst  )[0]    for r in rs ]
Out[3]: [[-2.0, 5.0], [-1.0, -3.0]]

In [4]:
```